# Trouble positioning Admob with GLSurfaceView

Tags: android

I have finally figured out how to display an AdView with my GLSurfaceView. Why doesn't AdMob make it easy? Anyway, I need help positioning my ad.

I set up everything programmatically (and probably terribly) because I can't find any good resources to help. I would like to position the AdView at the bottom and centered. I tried wrapping the ad in it's own layout, but this throws, "Child specified already has a parent error." I get the same error when I try to use a SMART_BANNER and when I try to set LayoutParams for the AdView.

Here's what I've got:

```
    mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(mRenderer);

    setAd();        
    setContentView(parentLayout);
}

private AdView adView;
private RelativeLayout parentLayout;
private void setAd() {
    parentLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    LayoutParams glParams = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    parentLayout.setLayoutParams(glParams);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_id));
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    parentLayout.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
    parentLayout.addView(adView);
}
```

The ad is present and functioning, just in the top left corner. I know the solution is easy, but I can't get it because I always do this in XML. How do we get it aligned bottom and centered??